# How the user can choose specific file location to save a file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, directory, path, filepicker

When pressing a button the user need to choose a file location (Pick a folder) to save a file. How can i implement it in flutter. Can i use file_picker package for picking the folder?

Answer (score 1):

Due to security issues Android doesn't allow saving files in the specific folder since android 8. In IOS also same security reasons are there for that issue, so I don't think this would be implementable above android 8.0 . but you can test in previous versions if its still working.